# Howto generate App_Licence.dll from command line

Tags: tfsbuild, licenses.licx

I have a web application which uses a 3. party component witch needs a licens in order to work properly. In Visual Studio there is an option to pre compile the license information by rightclicking on the license.licx file and choose "Build runtime license". This will generate the assembly App_License.dll. Hovever - this only works for web sites - not for web applications ("Build runtime license" will not appear when you rightclick the license.licx file.)

For web applications the license information will be embedded in the main assembly of the web application at compiletime. This is means that if you are using a dedicated TFS build server, then the 3. party component has to be installed on the build server even though it is supposed to be a per developer license aggreement. This is annoying and it clutters up our build server, which is used by many different projects.

It is possible to create a temporay website with the same 3. party license information and then use the "Build runtime license" which will generate a valid App_License.dll which we use in our web application. This works fine and now our build script just clears the license.licx file before compiling, so we do not have to have the 3. party component installed on the build server.

Is there anyway to precompile the App_Licence.dll from commandline, so we dont have to create a temporary website?

Kind regards
Peter Bøtker Frederiksen